# Why does strpos not work here?

Tags: php, strpos

Im making a function that checks if a certain username in the process of registration contains certain characters that I dont want the users to have in their username. And it echoes the user what characters they can use.

```
public function checkUsername($username){       
    if(!empty($username)){  
        $exceptions= "!@~`#$%^&*()+=/\,;:[]{  }|?,<>"
this is line 26 from the error ->if(strpos($username, $exceptions) !=== false ){
        //here it means that something was found
            echo "Cannot contain special characters except - and _ .";
            return false;
        }//since it returns false, nothing after this gets executed.
    if(strlen($username) < 6){
        echo "Username must be at least 6 characters long to register.";
        return false;
    }
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE BINARY username = ? ");
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$username);
    $stmt->execute();   
    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
        echo "Sorry username already exists";     
        return false;
    } else{
        return true;
      } 
    }
}//end of checkUsername
```

It gives me a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF on line 26.

Comment: Usually errors like this happen one line above and not on the actual line number itself. Seems you don't have a semi-colon in `$exceptions= "!@~`#$%^&*()+=/\,;:[]{  }|?,<>"

Answer (score 1):

Usually errors like this happen one line above and not on the actual line number itself.

Seems you don't have a closing semi-colon in

```
$exceptions= "!@~`#$%^&*()+=/\,;:[]{  }|?,<>"
```

Replace it with

```
$exceptions= "!@~`#$%^&*()+=/\,;:[]{  }|?,<>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous line is missing a semicolon

```
$exceptions= "!@~`#$%^&*()+=/\,;:[]{  }|?,<>";
```

Answer (score 0):

and `!===` is probably supposed to be `!==`

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few things are broken here.

First of all, strpos matches a whole string, not any included character.  You want to use preg_match here

Secondly, your comparator should be !== false, not !=== false, but by using preg_match, you won't need it.